# move Object according to the property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to `addSubView:eventCell` on the place compatible with `event.num`.
I have this code.

NSObject Event

```
@property NSString* title; 
@property NSInteger num1;
@property NSInteger num2;
```

ViewController.m

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* events;

- (void)setEventCell
{
    Event* event = [[Event alloc]init];
    event.title = ABC;
    event.num1 = 0;
    event.num2 = 0;
    [events addObject:event];

    for(Event* event in events){
        UIView* eventCell = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(event.num1 * 20, event.num2 * 20, 20, 20);
        eventCell.label1.text = event.title;
        [self.view addSubView:eventCell];
    }
}
```

The problem is that `eventCell` does not displayed on `view`.
When `event.num1 == 0` and `event.num2 == 0`,
I want to set `eventCell` on the position `x = 20, y = 20`.

Do you have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: please let us know more about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UILabel` in place of `UIView` and set title as `eventCell.text = event.title`

And also put a condition for frames as follows

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);
if(event.num1 == 0 && event.num2 == 0){
frame.origin.x = 20;
frame.origin.y = 20;
}
else{
frame.origin.x = event.num1*20;
frame.origin.y = event.num2*20;
}
eventCell.frame = frame;
```

or Else, Simply use frame

```
UILabel *eventCell = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+event.num1*20,20+event.num2*20, 20,20)]
```

Thanks

Satya

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to set background color to eventCell, to be sure that it
   is on self.view.
2. Try to check frame in debug.
3. "eventCell.label1.text" - is it custom view? Cause UIView class
       hasn't label1 property!